# Converting code using array to a code using Stacks/Queue

Tags: java, loops, stack, queue

So I have this following code that's checks elements within an array to see if they modulo to x (defined in the parameters).

I'm trying to rewrite the same code with either a stack or a queue and hopefully different loops, but I'm quite the beginner in these data types therefore I'm having a hard time implementing them.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Algorithm Checker (Array A, x)

For i <- 0 to n-1 do
    For j <- i+1  to n-1 do
        If A[i] modulo A[j] equals to x then
            Return A[i] and A[j]
        End If
    End for
    End for
```

Comment: "Rewrite code with a stack" is too broad. What is the language of your Code example?

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic In Java I guess would be appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you right. You fill the first stack `s1` with all elements of `A` and iterate by popping them off. In this loop, create `s2` as a copy of `s1` and also iterate through its elements by popping off the first element. You can then compare both elements. In Python-like pseudocode, it would look similar to

```py
s1 = A.toStack # It's pseudocode :-)

while !s1.isEmpty():
    elem1 = s1.pop()
    s2 = s1.copy()

    while !s2.isEmpty():
        elem2 = s2.pop()
        if elem1 % elem2 == x:
            return elem1 == elem2
```

Be aware that to keep the order in which elements are iterated, you have to fill `s1` in reverse order. The implementation in Java is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int[] AlgoChkr(int A[],int x)
 {      int B[] = new int[A.length];
    int j = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i<A.length ;i++    )
            {   if(A[i]%x ==0)
                    {
                     B[j] = A[i];
                     j++;
                    }
            }
    return B;
 }
```